# My footer is hidden by the map obtained via the Google Maps API

Tags: css, html, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API on my website, and when I try to reduce the width of my window, the footer is hidden by the map. My aim is to add a blank space between the map and the footer.

The result in a large window: [image: http://jaboste.dyndns.org/tmp/footer1.png]

The result in a smaller window: [image: http://jaboste.dyndns.org/tmp/footer2.png]

The html code of the page:

```
<section class="contact">
    <article class="contact">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <div class="carte">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
    </article>
</section>
<footer>
    <p class="align-droite">
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        Dolor sit amet
    </p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

The css code of the page:

```
footer{
        width:100%;
        font-family:'karla';
        text-align:right;
        margin-top:1%;
}
.carte{
        height:95%;
        margin-bottom:3%;
}
```

I've tried to add margin properties but nothing worked. Is there a solution?

Comment: You forgot to validate your HTML.  After I indented your code above, you can see that you're missing a closing tag on your `<div class="carte">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MSzut/) for css framework for header, footer and body. The css has been commented to  assist. Jsfiddle allows you to change the css values and view the changes with the run button.